# Installing PhantomJS 2 using NPM fails on Windows

Tags: windows, npm, phantomjs

I'm trying to install PhantomJS 2 for a project that requires support for mutation observers. When I use the following command:

```
npm install phantomjs2 --save-dev
```

I get the following error:

```
Unexpected platform or architecture: win32 x64
npm ERR! phantomjs2@2.0.0 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the phantomjs2@2.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the phantomjs2 package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls phantomjs2
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodej
s\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "phantomjs2" "--save-dev"
npm ERR! cwd g:\Web\GitHub\pet
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     g:\Web\GitHub\pet\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am using 64 bit Windows 7. Is PhantomJS 2 just not supported on my platform?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that package currently doesn't support installing PhantomJS 2 on Windows. Just download it from the [official page](http://phantomjs.org/download.html) and put the exe in a directory that is in the PATH.

Comment: Update the PATH "system" variable point to the directory where you have "phantomjs.exe" (My Computer>Properties>Advanced system settings>Advanced>Environment Variables>System Variables)